# What do the Ubuntu One emblems mean?

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-one, emblem

I decided to try out Ubuntu One for the first time. I added my computer via System -> Preferences -> Ubuntu One, and then I right-clicked on a folder and clicked "Synchronize on Ubuntu One". There was no immediate feedback that anything had happened, but now the folder's only sub-folder has some kind of Ubuntu One emblem on it:

[image: screenshot]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/FileSharing#Sync%20status). Essentially this one means the file or folder is not synchronised. There are another two emblems for synchronised and synchronising.

[image: Ubuntu One Not synchronized] [image: Ubuntu One Synchronizing] [image: Ubuntu One Synchronized]

Answer (score 4):

This particular Ubuntu One emblem means 'unsynchronised'. You can get a pretty good idea of what emblems mean by right clicking a file/folder, clicking properties and selecting the 'Emblems' tab:

[image: emblems]

As you can see there are other Ubuntu One emblems meaning 'updating' and 'synchronised'.